# Custom color of shapes (rectangle, circle, etc.,)

Tags: swift, xcode

Right now I am using Xcode 14.

I am a beginner which means I am mostly following YouTube tutorials. In one of the tutorials I am just stuck searching for "Color Literals".

I have tried to find the answer in google, but it didn't work.

I am attaching a snapshot of the tutorial which shows the feature that I am talking about.

I wonder the Xcode 14 is deprived of this feature.

I have tried to find that "Color Literal", but nothing can be found.

Comment: try typing `Color(#colorLiteral())` and XCode should show the color picker

Comment: You may find the following [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcode+color+literal) helpful.

Comment: For color literals see: https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-color-literals
However, if you are asking about "Custom color of shapes", they don't have to be color literals, you can always define a color as `Color(red: ..., green: ..., blue: ...)`, or use a predefined color like `Color.red`... and there are a few more wys to define a custom color.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.